# Try to include same .php file in Multiple rows

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGz43.jpg)**faculty.php** contains list of faculty information which is a dropdown list (already prepared)
I am trying to call the same file in different rows, but it is accessed only one time.

```
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Connection Failed. ".mysqli_connect_error);
}

$query = "select * from course where regul='$regulation' and year_sem='$sem'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query); 
?>

<table width='60%' border='1'>
     <tr> <th> COURSE CODE <th> COURSE TITLE <th> FACULTY NAME</tr>
       
 <?php
 if($result){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr> <td align='center'>";
        echo $row['ccode']."<td>";
        echo $row['ctitle']."<td>";
        *include("faculty.php");*
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
else{
     echo "<tr> <td colspan='3'>";
     echo " No Record Found";
}
```

i want to access the same file for multiple rows.... How?
(dropdown need to repeat for all the subject in the same semester)

Comment: why used `*` inside your `php` code ? why does not write proper code?

Comment: Please show the faculty.php or at least an excerpt to give a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: **Huge Hint**. Almost ALL HTML elements have a Start tag AND an End tag, for example `<td>` has a `</td>` as does `<th>` have a `</th>` If you dont use them, you will find very strange things happen, and different strange things in different browsers.

Comment: _I am trying to call the same file in different rows_ Not sure what that means, do you mean you want to `include faculty.php;` more than once in another script file?

Comment: <?php
 $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","vrcsedb");
 if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
      die("Connection Failed. ".mysqli_connect_error);
   }
$query = "select * from emp";
   $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
   
 echo "<select name='faculty' id='faculty'>";
 echo "<option value=''> Faculty </option>";
  if($result){
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "<option ='";
  echo $row['empid'];
  echo "'>";
  echo $row['empname']."</option>";
 }
}
else{
  echo " No Record Found";
}  
?>

Comment: This is my faculty.php